# How to determine counts of viruses from limiting dilution assay

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, biostatistics

My question relates to a common experiment in the field of virology. Let me give some background so you understand why I'm asking this question.

When producing virus for an experiment you typically use a small amount to infect a large population of cells, which serves to amplify the virus before all the cells are killed. After collecting the virus that is produced it is usually necessary to titer it. What you typically want is to ascertain the number of virus particles (plaque forming units or PFU) per milliliter (PFU/mL).

The way this is done is by limiting dilution assay (LDA), which is performed as follows:

1. Put equal numbers of cells in all wells of a 96 well plate (8x12)
2. Take your virus of unknown concentration and perform serial dilutions (e.g. starting from 10e-2 make serial 5-fold dilutions to span all 12 columns of the plate)
3. Use 100uL of each dilution to infect cells in the appropriate column (make enough of each dilution in step 2 so that you can infect every well in the column for a total of 8 replicates)
4. After a few days it is apparent by observation which wells were infected. As the concentration gets really low the likelihood of any well being infected becomes linearly proportional to the concentration. Ideally the least concentrated column will have no infected cells so you know you've diluted enough to see a difference from the highly concentrated virus.

This seems to follow a binomial distribution where the probability of getting infected depends on the concentration. The problem is that the virus concentration is poisson distributed. At higher concentrations the probability of infection is essentially 1, since the probability of not picking up a single virus is very small. At low concentrations you might pick up a virus or not so you have some infected wells, some uninfected.

What is the best way to make use of all of the data to estimate the PFU/mL? I was thinking poisson regression, but I'm actually not dealing with counts directly. Logistic regression makes intuitive sense, but I'm not sure how to combine it with the knowledge that any number of viruses getting into a well will have the same outcome: infection.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Bonus points for sensible error estimates.